# PTIJ: How do I write a bill of divorce for chulent?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

One of the commandments of Purim is משלוח מנות איש לרעהו - divorcing portions one from another. (I am aware that there is an opinion that this means "sending," but I'm trying to fulfill the obligation lechol habinyanim.)

A few problems have come up with this. Do the foods have to literally hand the bill of divorce to each other? This is very difficult to accomplish with inanimate objects.

Also, some of the names are tricky and don't appear in the [Shulchan Aruch's list of names](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x8161). For example, I'm sending chulent in mishloach manot this year. How am I supposed to write "chulent" in a bill of divorce? Is it טשולנט or צ'ולנט, or perhaps טשולענט or צ'ולענט? And what if I write a get divorcing chulent from chips: Is the spelling טשולענט alongside צ'יפס considered תרתי דסתרי (self-contradictory)?

Someone suggested adding the line [וכל שום שיש לה](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Gittin.34b.2?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in order to avoid the doubt regarding the spelling. However, this solution is invalid, because there is no [garlic](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9D) in the chulent.

So how can I spell the name correctly to prevent my food from becoming an aguna? Do any of our sources give us guidelines when writing bills of divorce for our food?

For practical advice, as always, CYLOR (Consult Your Local [O-Cmon](http://is.gd/ocmon) Rabbi).

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Charles/Charlie is discussed at https://law.tau.ac.il/sites/law.tau.ac.il/files/media_server/law_heb/dine_israel/published/published_L/Dinei30_HEBbaris.pdf, so maybe we can extrapolate

Comment: Shouldn't you just list it as its proper name, Chamin, which is easier to spell?

Comment: You don't put garlic in your chulent??? How can it taste good? That's why your spouse wants a divorce!

Comment: @DanF , I was thinking along similar lines. Lack of garlic and onions may have invalidated the chulent to begin with. Like pizza without mozzarella or pastrami without rye.

Comment: Your situation is even worse than you realize - the pasuk then says איש לרעהו, that these מנות have a din of each man to their friend - they each have their own individual name! We don't write a get "from this man to a woman"! How exactly are we supposed to know what chulent is being mishloach what chips? And it just gets worse, as you write the name by which they are called, and we call all of them chulent!

Comment: Just sayin', _cholent/chulent_ is spelled טשאלענט in Yiddish.

Comment: @ezra Meheicha Teisi?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Hey I'm not familiar with that term (gasp!)... Do you mind telling me what it means?

Comment: @ezra basically it means "where did you get that from"/"how do you know"?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות (Thanks for the definition) I speak Yiddish; that's how I know. :)

Comment: @rosends Who said chamin was more proper than cholent? At the very least, it's just as proper. Just because it's Hebrew doesn't make it more proper. AFAIK, the words "chamin" and "cholent" don't show up in the classic Rabbinic literature. :)

Comment: the talmud often talks about preparing chamin on shabbat, even for an istanis kohen on Yom Kippur! אם היה כהן גדול זקן או אסטניס מחמין לו חמין

Comment: @rosends חמין means warm food, not necessarily cholent. (See Jastrow) The OP is specifically asking concerning the Ashkenazi dish [cholent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholent). Only in recent times with the rise of Modern Hebrew has chamin become the equivalent to cholent. Thanks for pointing out where the word shows up in the Gemara.

Comment: and when the tosefta discusses being tovel in something chamin, it means any warm food? Like I would dip into soup!? I only dive into chulent so I assume that that's what the text means שטבל בחמין טהור קומקומים שהוא מלא חמין והטבילו טמא שפשפו או שהטביל בחמין טהור

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid all issues, you should use non-Jewish foods. A non-Jew can divorce without a shtar gittin. Unfortunately, Cholent is one of the three truly Jewish foods (along with Gefilte fish and matza). Fortunately, Cholent makes for a very messy Mishloach Manos, so you would be better off with an alternative anyway.

So if you want to be yotze v'nichnas l'chulei ama, I advise you to use two non-Jewish foods. Steamed oats and sushi make very good options. Since they are subject to safek bracha, they clearly are not Jewish foods.

Comment: And what about bagels?????!?!?!?!?11?!

Comment: @Yez Cholent, gefilte fish, and matza have their origin in various Halachos and are therefore (to the best of my knowledge), some of the only truly Jewish foods.

Comment: Tosefos gives the recipe for charoses, so I think it should make the list.

Comment: @Yez OR CHALLAH?

Answer (score 2):

As we see from [Bamidbar 11:5](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bemidbar/11.5#e1n7), "onion" and "garlic" are interchangeable:

> וְאֶת־הַבְּצָלִ֖ים וְאֶת־הַשּׁוּמִֽים

Therefore, you may write וכל בצל שיש לה, which will solve the problem in this case, provided that there is onion in the Cholent.  If not, see the other ingredients in that Passuk that may work as substitutes, such as melon or cucumbers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to concern yourself with the spelling of chulent at all. After Shabbat, chulent is essentially, "dead meat" or dead food.

You may be familiar with the Gemarah story (don't recall exact page, but I'm pretty sure it's in Talmud Shabbat) that says that Shabbat is what makes the food taste good. Shabbat has its own *neshama*, and that neshama enters the chulent. When Shabbat ends, the neshama disappears from the chulent and the chulent is dead meat.

You don't need to divorce dead meat.