# PTIJ: Taanis Esther

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In the Megilas Esther - Esther Hamalka saves the Jews. The day before Purim is known as Taanis Esther. Why would anyone have (Taanis) complaints to her?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I thought it meant that we were to be more like her, and as she was middle eastern, we were commanded to be as tan as Esther.

Comment: @rosends You mean [as green as Esther](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90076/1569)?

Comment: @ba Olive it up to you.

Answer (score 4):

On the day before we celebrate the salvation of Purim, we commemorate what happened on the day before we were saved. That was the day that Esther invited Haman to a private party with just her and the King. All of the Jews thought that Esther had turned her back on them, as the Gemara in Megilla (15b) states was exactly Esther's goal:

> מה ראתה אסתר שזימנה את המן ר' נחמיה אומר כדי שלא יאמרו ישראל אחות יש לנו בבית המלך
>
> What did Esther see that she invited Haman [to the private party]? R' Nechemia says in order that the Jews not say "we have a sister in the King's house"

So, the Jews all had taanis on her.

Since this happened on Pesach, and we don't want to have bad feelings on Pesach, we instead commemorate this by having taanis on Esther on the day before we celebrate Purim.

Answer (score 1):

Esther was known to cause unnecessary afflictions, to many (perhaps through sarcasm). People thus had great taanis on her. We remember this with Taanis Esther. As is accounted in the Megillah:

5:7

> וַתַּ֥עַן אֶסְתֵּ֖ר וַתֹּאמַ֑ר שְׁאֵלָתִ֖י וּבַקָּשָׁתִֽי׃
>
> Esther afflicted [them] saying only my requests!

7:3

> וַתַּ֨עַן אֶסְתֵּ֤ר הַמַּלְכָּה֙ וַתֹּאמַ֔ר אִם־מָצָ֨אתִי חֵ֤ן בְּעֵינֶ֙יךָ֙ הַמֶּ֔לֶךְ וְאִם־עַל־הַמֶּ֖לֶךְ ט֑וֹב תִּנָּֽתֶן־לִ֤י נַפְשִׁי֙ בִּשְׁאֵ֣לָתִ֔י וְעַמִּ֖י בְּבַקָּשָׁתִֽי׃
>
> Queen Esther afflicted: “If Your Majesty will do *me* the favor, and if it *pleases* Your Majesty, let my life be granted me as my wish, and my people as my request.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple reason to complain against Esther.

Many people think, "Oh this an *easy* fast." They think that because the day is "short" it's easy. C'mon, who are they kidding?

First of all, in most of U.S., and in most years, daylight saving time occurred before Purim. (Some years, it hasn't.) So, in NYC area nightfall is around 7:45 - late enough. OK, if it were any other fast day, I'd be able to eat then, right?

But nooooo ... along comes Esther who not only has a fast named after her, but she has a book named after her, too. And we have to read her book out loud, publicly, and wait for kids to make noise each time her enemy's name is pronounced. (Feh! What do these pre-Bar Mitzvah kids care about all the adults fasting, anyway?) All that takes extra time, and I can't eat until after her book has read to completion. So, by the time I get home, it's like close to 9 PM.

Y'know, this all Esther's fault. And, that's the **least** of my complaints against her. I'm just starting...